Browser automatically upgrades http:// requests to https:// - ssl_error_rx_record_too_long
I have an application running on http://localhost:8064. It does not use https, but goes to external website to full fill order, But I am getting Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long and not sure what is wrong happening here and how to resolve it.
I am attaching two screenshots that show the request and response received from Dell. It seems that the header "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1" might be converting the URL from 'http' to 'https', leading to this issue.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Content-Security-Policy: Upgrading insecure request ‘
http://localhost:8064/lr?TARGET_URL=http%3a%2f%2fmywebsite.com%3a55800%2fitem%2fportal%3fNavigationTarget%3dpcd%3aportal_content%2fcontent%2fglobal%2fsrm%2froles%2fshop_requestr%2ffl_proshoprequester%2ffl_goshopping%2fcreate_shop_cart%26NavMode%3d3%26catalogWindowID%3dWIDx1721750505372%26UsePost%3dTrue%26RESUME_ID%3dOCI%26&CODEPAGE=UTF-8’
to use ‘https’

